# MVC FluentNhibernate where to create ISessionFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

I am just starting to learn FluentNhibernate using ASP.NET MVC 3, so pardon me if this question sounds stupid or I am not clear enough.

My solution consists of 2 projects: Web interface and the Business layer. Below i the code block to initialize the NHibernate session factory:

```
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }

public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
{
    get
    {
        if (_sessionFactory == null) InitializeSessionFactory();
        return _sessionFactory;
    }
}

public static void InitializeSessionFactory()
{
    SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(m => m.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connString")).ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MySampleObjectMap>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}

public static ISession OpenSession()
{
    return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
}
```

So, my question is that where do I have to instantiate and initialize the NHibernate Session factory?

1. On Business layer so that the persistence layer will be separate, or,
2. Do in the Global.asax.cs of the MVC Web project?

   What are the benefits of each that I am not aware of?